# How to initialize a set() in code to be compiled as pypy's rpython?

Tags: python, compilation, set, pypy

I want to compile some python code using pypy's rpython translator. A very simple toy example that doesn't do anything :

```
def main(argv):
 a = []
 b = set(a)
 print b
 return 0

def target(driver,args):
        return main,None
```

If I compile it as:

```
python2.6 ~/Downloads/pypy-1.4.1-src/pypy/translator/goal/translate.py --output trypy trypy.py
```

It doesn't compile, rather just halts with errors something like this:

```
[translation:ERROR]  AttributeError': 'FrozenDesc' object has no attribute 'rowkey'
[translation:ERROR]  .. v1 = simple_call((type set), v0)
[translation:ERROR]  .. '(trypy:3)main'
[translation:ERROR] Processing block:
[translation:ERROR]  block@0 is a <class 'pypy.objspace.flow.flowcontext.SpamBlock'>
[translation:ERROR]  in (trypy:3)main
[translation:ERROR]  containing the following operations:
[translation:ERROR]        v0 = newlist()
[translation:ERROR]        v1 = simple_call((type set), v0)
[translation:ERROR]        v2 = str(v1)
[translation:ERROR]        v3 = simple_call((function rpython_print_item), v2)
[translation:ERROR]        v4 = simple_call((function rpython_print_newline))
[translation:ERROR]  --end--
```

If I take out the set() function it works. How do you use sets in rpython?

Comment: Seems to be an issue with PyPy, not your code.

Comment: Have you tried `b = set()`? Then `b.add(x)` if needed?

Comment: So, it seems one doesn't use sets in RPython... Good old dicts should do the trick, right?

Answer (score 4):

So its official, set() is not supported in rpython. Thanks TryPyPy.

Comment: Though I don't understand why it can't be added. If it's just built on top of a dict, one can even write a myset class and use it. Though it will be better to use the same names as python.

Answer (score 0):

<s>While RPython does not recognize `set` it is capable of importing the `Sets` module.</s>

I seem to have spoken a bit too soon. The `sets` module uses three parameter `getattr` calls, RPython does not support the optional third paramemter.

This can be fixed by:

1. In the pypy install directory, under `lib-python\2.7\`, copy `sets.py` to your project directory, and rename the copy `rsets.py`.
2. Search for the five instances of `getattr` in the file. Remove the last parameter (the default return value), which is in each case `None`.
3. Prepend `from rsets import Set as set` to your RPython code.

In each of the five instances, should the element not be hashable, it will return an `AttributeError` rather than a `TypeError`, but will otherwise work as expected.